# objc_msgSend EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using a close button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, uibutton

In my project I've added a close button in the top corner right like this:

```
int closeBtnOffset = 10;
UIImage* closeBtnImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"popupCloseBtn.png"];
UIButton* closeBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[closeBtn setImage:closeBtnImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[closeBtn setFrame:CGRectMake( background.frame.origin.x + background.frame.size.width - closeBtnImg.size.width - closeBtnOffset, 
                               background.frame.origin.y ,
                               closeBtnImg.size.width + closeBtnOffset, 
                               closeBtnImg.size.height + closeBtnOffset)];
[closeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(closePopupWindow) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[bigPanelView addSubview: closeBtn];
```

The closePopupWindw method looks like this:

```
-(void)closePopupWindow
{
    //remove the shade
    [[bigPanelView viewWithTag: kShadeViewTag] removeFromSuperview];
    [self performSelector:@selector(closePopupWindowAnimate) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];

}
```

The build succeeds but when I click the closeBtn button, the program shuts down with this message: http://i45.tinypic.com/ddndsl.png

I think that there is nothing wrong with the code since I copied it from another project and it works well there, but in the other project they didn't use ARC, and I'm not sure if that is the problem.

**EDIT:**

```
-(void)closePopupWindowAnimate
{

    //faux view
    __block UIView* fauxView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];
    [bgView addSubview: fauxView];

    //run the animation
    UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft |
    UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction    |
    UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState;

    //hold to the bigPanelView, because it'll be removed during the animation

    [UIView transitionFromView:bigPanelView toView:fauxView duration:0.5 options:options completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        //when popup is closed, remove all the views
        for (UIView* child in bigPanelView.subviews) {
            [child removeFromSuperview];
        }
        for (UIView* child in bgView.subviews) {
            [child removeFromSuperview];
        }

        [bgView removeFromSuperview];

    }];
}
```

Comment: show us `closePopupWindowAnimate`

Comment: First turn on the zombies in your project so that you can get the readable error message on the console if your app crashes `Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme->Diagnostics->Enable Zombie Objects for objective-c`

Comment: *** -[MTPopupWindow performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x8091610

Comment: Maybe it has something to do that there was a xib file in the first project where I copied it form. Now I'm using storyboards

Comment: you are accessing object which have been released already, it is always good idea to use properties, and set the properties type `strong` so they can retain place in memory as long as your view is active.

Comment: `self` is deallocated between the moment you call `[self performSelector:@selector(closePopupWindowAnimate) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];` and the moment it is actually called (0.1 seconds later). You need to post more of your code if you want more detail.

Answer (score 3):

You are accessing object which have been released already, it is always good idea to use properties, and set the properties type `strong`(using `ARC`) so they can retain place in memory as long as your view is active.

Declare your `UIButton` as the class Property it will solve your problem. You should see also that your button is added on `bigPanelView` and you are removing this view before you call the method `closePopupWindowAnimate`

Comment: What else do I need to add besides @property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *closeBtn;?

Comment: all objects which you are accessing in your view, you could release them by creating a dealloc method in your class by setting them to nil.

Comment: I added the property, synthiszed it and change closeBtn with _closeBtn but it still gives me the same error

Comment: your button is added on `bigPanelView` and you are removing this view before you call the method `closePopupWindowAnimate`

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *closeBtn;
property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *bgView;
property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *bigPanelView; and I also have synthesized them, still the same error message, bgView and bigPanelView were in interface first but I changed them to property and I also edited my code with _bgView isntead of bgView, same with closeBtn and bigPanelView

Comment: add this line after the method call  `[[bigPanelView viewWithTag: kShadeViewTag] removeFromSuperview];`

Comment: I've put that line after [self performSelector:@selector(closePopupWindowAnimate) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1]; and again, still the same...

Comment: `[self performSelector:@selector(closePopupWindowAnimate) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];` set the object which you are sending, i see your message now for error, i believe it is because you are sending nil `withObject`, when you add some details you should updated in your question!

Comment: I didn't change that line of code, it was always that from the beginning ? Any idea what causes this error or how I can solve it?

Comment: post your complete code how you defining the properties and views in your question

Comment: Here are the files: http://pastebin.com/p5VhWNpq and http://pastebin.com/QPXbG1uK

Comment: when you use properties then access all properties with `self.`  e.g `self.closeBtn` secondly it is obvious from your code any error, but I would suggest you to put the break point in your code or `NSLog` to check the objects or methods which are called and not called...

Comment: The only other thing that has anything to do with the code provided above, is this line in another view controller:     [MTPopupWindow showWindowWithContent:@"text1" insideView:self.view]; where exactly should I start debugging and setting a breakpoint since I'm not sure how to debug this problem...

Comment: you should set the break points in the application where you are in doubt that there might be issues

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look, I suspect the problem may be the performSelector call in closePopupWindow: the button is retained by bigPanelView, but this is released in the first line. This may mean that 'self' is then deallocated before the performSelector is called.

As a matter of style, avoid using view tags: it's far better to define properties to relevant views in some kind of parent object. This also makes it easier to avoid retain cycles and early releases like the problem you have here